# Is there any way to visualize the field on adaptive mesh with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, field, mesh

I am a beginner in gnuplot. Recently I tried to visualize a pressure field on  adaptive mesh.

[image]

Firstly I got the coordinates of nodes and center of the cell and the pressure value at the center of the cell.

[image]

And, I found something difficult to deal with. That is the coordinates in x and y directions are not regular, which made me feel hard in preparing the format of source data. For regular and equal rectangular case, I can do something just like x-y-z format. But is there any successful case in adaptive mesh?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have some x,y,z data which is in no regular grid (well, your adaptive mesh).
I'm not fully sure whether this is what you are looking for, but
gnuplot can grid the data for you, i.e. inter-/extrapolating your data within a regular grid and then plot it.
Check `help dgrid3d`.

**Code:**

```
### grid data
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:200] {
        x = rand(0)*100-50
        y = rand(0)*100-50
        z = sin(x/15)*sin(y/15)
        print sprintf("%g %g %g",x,y,z)
    }
set print

set view equal xyz
set view map
set multiplot layout 1,2

    set title "Original data with no regular grid"
    unset dgrid3d
    splot $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 lc palette notitle
    
    set title "Gridded data"
    set dgrid3d 100,100 qnorm 2
    splot $Data u 1:2:3 w pm3d

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to you! I can understand what you said. Actually, I did some trial on this work of interpolation. Actually my work is to use the adaptive mesh to capture the interface. Therefore the grid near the interface is so dense. I have nearly 100,000 cells.

Comment: I have nearly 100,000 cells. Fortunately I successfully do the interpolation with just about 2000 points in each direction. However I found the information near the interface is still not so good for I use regular grid in place of the smaller adaptive one.  I am looking for a way to reserve my source data and visualize them. Still very grateful for your reply!

Comment: 2000x2000 = 4 million pixels is not good enough for 100'000 cells? Maybe you can share the image to illustrate what still needs to be improved?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the size of each cell, you can use the "boxxyerror" plotting style. Let xdelta and ydelta be half the size of a cell along the x-axis and y-axis.

[image: figure to show xdelta and ydelta]

Script:

```
$datablock <<EOD
# x y xdelta ydelta pressure
 1  1 1 1 0
 3  1 1 1 1
 1  3 1 1 1
 3  3 1 1 3
 2  6 2 2 4
 6  2 2 2 4
 6  6 2 2 5
 4 12 4 4 6
12  4 4 4 6
12 12 4 4 7
EOD

set xrange [-2:18]
set yrange [-2:18]

set palette maxcolors 14
set style fill solid 1 border lc black 

plot $datablock using 1:2:3:4:5 with boxxyerror fc palette title "mesh", \
     $datablock using 1:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb "gray30" title "point" 

pause -1
```

In this script, 5-column data (x, y, xdelta, ydelta, pressure) is given for "boxxyerror" plot. To colorize the cells, the option "fc palette" is required.

Result:

[image: figure resulted from the script]

I hope this figure is what you are looking for.

Thanks.